# how to accelerate c++ for loop code into query using MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

code of c++ sub function

## insert data into MySQL

```
bool mysqlinsert2(int sourceindex,int targetindex,string source,string target)
    {
        MYSQL *conn_ptr;
        conn_ptr = mysql_init(NULL);

        if(!conn_ptr)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"mysql_init failed\n");
            //return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        conn_ptr = mysql_real_connect(conn_ptr,"localhost","root","nlpgroup","testdb",0,NULL,0);

        if(conn_ptr)
        {
            int abc;
            char sql_buffer[500] = {0};
            sprintf(sql_buffer,"insert into EM2 (sourceindex,targetindex,source,target) values(\"%d\",\"%d\",\"%s\",\"%s\")",sourceindex,targetindex,source.c_str(),target.c_str());
            if((abc = mysql_query(conn_ptr,sql_buffer)))
            {
                printf("error code:%s\n",mysql_error(conn_ptr));
            }
            mysql_close(conn_ptr);
            return true;
            //connection succees
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error code: %d  %s %s\n",mysql_errno(conn_ptr),mysql_sqlstate(conn_ptr),mysql_error(conn_ptr));
            mysql_close(conn_ptr);
            return false;
            //return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

---

## code for run loop and input the for loop index and value into MySQL by calling the function mysqlinsert2

```
void write_token_to_data()
    {
        typedef double* DynamicMatrix[l+m];
        // DynamicMatrix Count;
        typedef double* DynamicMatrix2[l+m];
        //DynamicMatrix2 Prob;
        for(int i=0; i<(l+m); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<(l+m); j++)
            {
                if(mysqlinsert2(i,j,combine[i],combine[j]))
                {
                    cout<<"insert OK!!"<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"insert failed"<<endl;
                }


            }
        }
        
    }//end of function
```

---

when MySQL insert ok the program will return the "insert ok!!"
so , here 's my question

these query could be until 30000*30000 times
and i want to know how to accelerate this, maybe i could optimize the MySQL setting or change the code in c++ , and i want it have same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of remarks:

- move opening and closing MySQL connection outside of your `mysqlinsert` method. Opening a connection is a slow operation, so it makes sense to do it once and only reopen it if the connection is lost before you are finished;
- using prepared SQL statement is also supposed to speed things up;
- consider using batch inserts, so that you insert N rows at a time (try N=100, for example).

Comment: the batch inserts the very important is how can i keep the value until the loop continuing ?

Comment: Do you mean incrementing the value? You can, for example, generate an array of rows which you want to insert (changing values the way you see fit) and then return the value corresponding to the last inserted row.

Answer (score 3):

Several improvements you can make:

1. Place those two functions in a class, keep the `MYSQL *conn_ptr` as a member field on that class. Then your mysqlinsert2 function needs not create and destroy the connection every time.

   ```cpp
   class MyInserter {
   public:
     MyInserter() {
       conn_ptr = mysql_init(NULL);
       if (!conn_ptr) throw ...;
       conn_ptr = mysql_real_connect(conn_ptr, ...);
       if (!conn_ptr) throw ...;
     }
     ~MyInserter() {
       mysql_close(conn_ptr);
     }
     bool mysqlinsert2(...) { ... }
     void write_token_to_data() { ... }

   private:
     MYSQL *conn_ptr;
   }
   ```
2. Use [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-function-overview.html) and [bound parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-bind-param.html). This will not only speed up your queries, but will also prevent SQL injection attacks (i.e. someone putting a quote character in the string you're inserting).
3. Instead of using `char sql_buffer[500]` and `sprintf`, consider using `std::ostringstream`. This avoids buffer overflows and can make for more readable code. Note the below code would change if you were doing (2) above as well:

   ```cpp
   std::ostringstream out;
   out << "insert into EM2 (sourceindex,targetindex,source,target) values(\"" << sourceindex << "\",\"" << targetindex << "\",\"" << source << "\",\"" << target << "\")"";
   std::string sql_string = out.str();
   ... mysql_query(conn_ptr, sql_string.c_str()) ...
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You are opening a new mysql connection for every insert which is going to hurt your performance a lot. Open a connection and keep it open until you have completed all of your inserts. Opening a new connection has significant overhead.

There is also overhead associated with transactions so you also most likely want to do many inserts per transaction. See this for details: [using transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html#trx)

Comment: i used to try move mysql connection out of this function and it could be insert error after maybe 10,20 times

Comment: i will try transactions and batch insert first,is that  any sample,like for loop insert ??

Comment: Your connection was probably lost. You might want to check if the connection is still alive and recreate it if needed.